# Using `prefix {}` method instead of `all { byMethod { } }` in Ratpack causes 405 Method Not Allowed - what's wrong?

Tags: groovy, ratpack

I've just started reading "Learn Ratpack", in one of the examples from the very beginning of the book, the author uses 'all', 'byMethod', 'get' and 'post' to exemplify how to parse request data, the way that he does it work, but I've tried using 'prefix', 'get' and 'post' but I can't get the same result, it's returning 405-Method Not Allowed.

I tried to find something in the docs, but I couldn't see why the behavior with 'prefix'.

Example version

```
import static ratpack.groovy.Groovy.ratpack
import ratpack.form.Form

ratpack {
    handlers {
        all {
            byMethod {
                get {
                  //In the exemple he sends a html form
                }
                post {
                  //And here he parses it.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

405 version

```
import static ratpack.groovy.Groovy.ratpack
import ratpack.form.Form

ratpack {
    handlers {
        prefix("parsing-request-data") {
            get{
               //From here all the same
```

That's it, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use multiple different HTTP methods for the same relative path, you still need to create such handlers using `byMethod {}` method. Otherwise, the first handler in the chain that matches the relative path handles the request, and it may fail or succeed. *(In your case POST request fails with **405 Method Not Allowed** because the `get` handler handles the request and it finds an incorrect HTTP method in the request. If you would like to see the GET request to fail instead of the POST one - reorder methods so the `post {}` is the first handler in the chain.)*

This `byMethod {}` method allows to register multiple handlers for the same relative path, and those handlers will be resolved based on the request's HTTP method. In case of using `prefix {}` method you may access `byMethod {}` method in the `path {}` helper method:

```
import static ratpack.groovy.Groovy.ratpack

ratpack {

    handlers {

        prefix("parsing-request-data") {
            path {
                byMethod {
                    post {
                        response.send("A response returned from POST /parsing-request-data\n ")
                    }

                    get {
                        response.send("A response returned from GET /parsing-request-data\n")
                    }
                }
            }

            get("test") {
                response.send("A response returned from GET /parsing-request-data/test\n")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a few curl commands to test it:

```
$ curl -i -X GET http://localhost:5050/parsing-request-data    
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
content-length: 51

A response returned from GET /parsing-request-data

$ curl -i -X POST http://localhost:5050/parsing-request-data    
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
content-length: 53

A response returned from POST /parsing-request-data

$ curl -i -X GET http://localhost:5050/parsing-request-data/test
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
content-length: 56

A response returned from GET /parsing-request-data/test
```